# NDK Detect if application is debuggable

Tags: android, android-ndk

Im using  the following code to check if inside the AndroidManifest.xml the debuggable tag is set to true or false.

```
strcpy( name, "ro.debuggable" );
__system_property_get( name, buf );
__android_log_print( ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "ro.debuggable", "%s",buf );
```

But either way it always return 0...

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

The information of the debuggable tag in the AndroidManifest.xml is in ApplicationInfo. You need to get the information in Java side.

```
/* exception handling code is omitted */
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
ApplicationInfo ai = new ApplicationInfo();
ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
if ((ai.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE) ==
        ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE ) {
    /* android:debuggable="true" */
}
```

Comment: How can I get that in C/C++ with the NDK?

Comment: You need to use JNI.  Also your code in your original question is using a huge honking heap of private APIs.  Don't do that.

Comment: What do you mean? You mean that I shouldn't use __system_property_get?
In any case any snippets to run the Java code above from Kazuki directly in C/C++ code using JNI, I can't seems to find any definition in the NDK for the instructions above.

Comment: You need to implement getting ApplicationInfo in Java and giving the information to native via JNI like [Using NDK to Call C code from Android Apps](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/49.html).